# Get the courses a student doesn't attend

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL and would like to get some help on this query.

I have 3 tables: `"Students"`, `"Courses"`, `"Attendance"`:

```
"Students" has these columns:
s_ID (primary key), name

"Courses" has these columns:
c_ID (primary key), courseName

"Attendance" has these columns:
s_ID (foreign key), c_ID (foreign key)
```

A student can attend a number of courses.

What I want is a query that will retrieve the ids of all of the courses which a student with a given id does not attend.

Comment: What have you tried?  `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN/NULL` are a few options...

Comment: Doesn't like, does that mean does not attend? What have you tried so far? You know trying different solutions is a great way learning SQL...

Comment: oops, i meant "does not attend", gonna edit that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses c WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Attendance a WHERE a.s_ID = @studentID AND a.c_ID = c.c_ID)
```

This selects all courses where no entry exists in `Attendance` with a given student ID and the course ID from the `Courses` table.

This assumes that you can replace `@studentID` with a specific ID, maybe passed as a parameter.

Comment: It works, thanks. But... Is there possibly a query that has better performance? Performance is very important for this query.

Comment: @Erran That would be a different question. And why would performance matter for a homework question?

Comment: Well it's not really a homework question... I just changed the names of the tables and such so that it would be more understandable. By the way, sorry for being vague, i'm still a beginner and lack experience and knowledge.